# How to play beep audio file during outgoing call and transmit to receiver

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

We have implemented pjsua2 library for calls. We are facing some issue in playing audio during outgoing calls. We have also implemented call recording functionality which is working fine. I am not sure how to play a wav file during call which can be heard by receiver too.

We have checked pjsua2 document which is not that up to mark.

```
getPlayer().createPlayer("file:///android_asset/1540Hz14s8000.wav");
audioMedia.startTransmit(getPlayer());
getCap_med().startTransmit(getPlayer());


  public static AudioMediaPlayer getPlayer() {
        if (player == null) {
            player = new AudioMediaPlayer();
        }
        return player;
    }

public static AudioMedia getCap_med() throws Exception {
        if (cap_med == null) {
            cap_med = MyApp.ep.audDevManager().getCaptureDevMedia();
        }
        return cap_med;
    }
```

Please help me, I have already spend almost a week.

Comment: What was your output based on what you tried?

Comment: @GiddyNaya We wants like while doing outgoing calls, at that time we want to play some beep media file. By using above code, nothing happened in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are transmitting the call audio to the .wav file (this is only correct when recording), what you should be doing is transmitting the .wav file to the call audio.

Instead of:

```
audioMedia.startTransmit(getPlayer());
getCap_med().startTransmit(getPlayer());
```

You need to do this:

```
getPlayer().startTransmit(audioMedia);
getPlayer().startTransmit(getCap_med());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me try this code in my project.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how i can play a wave file and transmit that sound to my sound device ,recorder and receiver of the call?